# Using large rasters in PostGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, raster, raster2pgsql

I successfully imported a **7 gb** raster into my PostGIS database using the following script
`raster2pgsql.exe -I -c -d -t 100x100  -s  <SRID> <file_path> public.<table_name> | <psql_connexion>`

The problem I encountered is when I try to load the raster in QGIS it takes a lifetime and sometimes it freezes.

Do you have any idea how can I load my raster quickly?

Do I have to change something in the loading parameters specially the -t?

Comment: The switch to use is `-l` https://postgis.net/docs/using_raster_dataman.html#RT_Raster_Overviews.

Comment: Rasters from PostgreSQL do not work well in QGIS. I would keep them on the disk.